# %> %> Characters appearing in IIS 7.5

Tags: asp-classic

Moved a Classic ASP/VBScript Web site from Windows 2003 server /IIS 6.0 to Windows 2008 server / IIS 7.5 and am now seeing these characters %> %> appear in some of the Web pages. Wondering if anyone else has seen this and what I can do to fix it. Went line by line and could not find any unclose scripts. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Classic ASP is not installed by default on IIS 7, so you'll need to enable it before the processor will handle ASP pages.

More info: http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/running-classic-asp-applications-on-iis-7-and-iis-8/classic-asp-not-installed-by-default-on-iis